Issue with importing .geojson files in an Astro project
I'm working on a project with Astro and I'm having trouble importing a .geojson file. I've added the type declaration to src/types/declarations.d.ts and updated my tsconfig.json, but I'm still getting the following error:
Cannot find module '../../data/recorregut-maplibre.geojson' or its corresponding type declarations. ts (2307)

Here are some additional details:
File src/pages/components/Route.astro:
---
import routegeojson from '../../data/recorregut-maplibre.geojson';
---
<section id="recorregut" class="py-20 bg-gray-100 min-h-screen flex items-center justify-center">
  <div class="container mx-auto">
    <h2 class="text-4xl font-bold mb-4">Recorregut</h2>
    <p class="text-xl">Informació sobre el nostre recorregut.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="map" class="w-full h-96"></div>
</section>

File src/types/declarations.d.ts:
declare module '*.geojson' {
  const value: any;
  export default value;
}

File tsconfig.json:
{
  "extends": "astro/tsconfigs/strict",
  "include": ["src/types/declarations.d.ts", "src/**/*"]
}

The file recorregut-maplibre.geojson exists in src/data/.
Does anyone know what might be causing this issue or how I can fix it? Thanks in advance!

astro is using vite under the hood. probably would need to set up a vite loader in the astro config. or you could just rename the file to recorregut-maplibre.json and it would just work :)
